# regedit and cmd and .exe file don't open

Tags: cmd, exe, regedit

I made a mistake. I wrote a wrong command on cmd which cause changing the type of the extension .exe to cabinet

this the command I wrote:

```
assoc .exe=cabinet
```

I need solution for this problem.

Comment: Assoc is a builtin of `cmd.exe` if I understand that correctly. Hmm, exe. `Cmd` should still work if you take windows\system32\cmd.exe and copy it to cmd.com so you can run it. Once you have an administrator session of cmd, you should be able to run assoc again to fix the problem. Same trick (.exe -> .com) should also work for regedit.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or perhaps one better suited for another site in the Stack Exchange family, like Super User?

Answer (score 0):

just done some quick research so hopefully this helps.
Press `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` to open the task manager. Then go to file and whole the `Ctrl` key as you press `Run new task`.

This should open a command prompt window.
You can now run the command `assoc .exe=exefile` and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things.

1. You should just be able to do `assoc .exe=exefile` in command prompt (cmd).

If for whatever reason that doesn't work...

2. You'll need to open the Windows task manager and do hold `CTRL` while selecting `File` >> `New Task (Run...)` which will open a command prompt window.

If for whatever reason neither of those two options work then I'd recommend restoring Windows to the last stable system image back up.  Microsoft actually has some documentation that I reviewed before posting to make sure I was thinking about this correctly.

I replicated your issue on a Windows vm to make sure that it works on the latest version of Windows 10.